# Adding gradient to UILabel through extension

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, gradient

as you probably know, if you try to set a gradient background to an UILabel it overwrites the text.
I would like to write an extension to UILabels in order to put a gradient background.
This is my code, but the gradient is put in a square moved down and right to the label. I cannot understand why, since I am using the same frame

```
public extension UILabel {
    func applyGradientToLabelAtAngle(_ angle : CGFloat, _ color1 : UIColor, _ color2 : UIColor){
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame = self.frame
        gradient.colors = [color1.cgColor, color2.cgColor]
        gradient.calculatePoints(for: angle)
        let index = self.layer.superlayer!.sublayers!.firstIndex(of: self.layer)!
        self.layer.superlayer!.sublayers!.insert(gradient, at: index)
        
    }
}
```

edit: calculatePoints function calculate the locations, not important for the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insufficient information. Your code works fine for me when I call it like this:

```
    let lab = UILabel()
    lab.text = "Howdy there"
    lab.sizeToFit()
    lab.frame.origin = .init(x:100, y:100)
    self.view.addSubview(lab)
    lab.applyGradientToLabelAtAngle(.pi, .green, .red)
```

The problem is evidently that you *not* calling it like that. But you didn't say how you *are* calling it. I suspect that you are calling it at the wrong time, namely at a time when the all-important `self.frame` is not yet known.

Comment: Thank you, I had to call it in viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: Yep, that's the right place. But be careful.  That method is called a lot so you can end up with a lot of gradient layers.